# Is it possible to create a single link that always takes the person to their country's website?

Tags: html, hyperlink, dns

I tried to find the answer to this on the web but as far as i can tell i don't even know how to ask the question correctly, but for example:

Let's say i wanted to provide a link to Amazon, but i wanted the person who clicked the link to be taken to their country's website, such that those in the US would be taken to .com, those in the UK would be taken to .co.uk, etc.

Is this possible (in HTML only)? If so, could you give me an example of how to do it? Or provide a source for more info?

Thanks.

Comment: People going to your website through a VPN might get completely unexpected results...

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it using php!
There are other methods you can use from @Dragos answer's!

```
    function RTLInfo($locale) {
        $RTL_locales = array('en', 'fa', 'hi');
        return in_array($locale, $RTL_locales);
    }
?>
<html lang="<?= $locale?>" dir="<?= RTLInfo($locale) ? 'rtl' : 'ltr' ?>" >
    <body class="<?= $locale?> <?= RTLInfo($locale) ? 'rtl' : 'ltr' ?>">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to detect the user's locale and manipulate it dynamically for your link.

Here s a ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Localization/Web_Localizability/Creating_localizable_web_applications